SonarQube Jacoco Coverage Showing 0 after importing scala module dependency in Java Springboot App (Strange..)
We have Spring boot Java App. Jacoco coverage is showing zero in SonarQube when I import scala module(uses scoverage) as dependency. If I remove this dependency, it works perfectly fine in SonarQube. We 're building using ado pipeline.
However, it works in my local machine always with/without dependency.
Java App POM:
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>
    <source.version>${java.version}</source.version>
    <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
    <sonar.sources>src/main/java</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${project.basedir}/target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
    </sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <sonar.projectBaseDir>.</sonar.projectBaseDir>
    <sonar.exclusions>
        src/test/**
    </sonar.exclusions>
    <jacoco.version>0.8.11</jacoco.version>
</properties>

